# Parse error in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to make a bash script for each time I set up a new linux system. My problem is I am getting an error saying parse error:

```
condition expected: =
```

I think the problem is that it is inside a while loop because it works when I remove it, but the while loop is kinda important for my program so cant just remove it. The script is meant to make a list which shows the options I can do in my script and it is supposed to have colors and a way to check if the option has ben ran before. The script seems to stop working after the line:
while [ $loop = 1 ]; do
When I try to run without the while loop it works so I think this may be a cause of the problem.

```
loop=1
scriptstatus=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 );
whatitdoes=('Install terminal programs' 'Install security programs' 'Install normal programs' 'Install spotify' 'Customize gnome' 'Install and customize zsh' 'Install etcher' 'Not yet run' 'Not yet run');

#'$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 1)Not yet run$(tput sgr0)'

while [ $loop = 1 ]; do
    answer=""
    clear
    echo "$(tput bold) Script:    What script does:     Status:$(tput sgr0)"
    COUNTER=0
    while [  $COUNTER -lt 7 ]; do

        if [[ $scriptstatus[$COUNTER] = 0 ]]
        then
            echo " ["$COUNTER"] "$'\x1d'" ${whatitdoes[$COUNTER]} "$'\x1d'" $(tput bold)$(tput setaf 1)Not yet run$(tput sgr0)"
        elif [[ $scriptstatus[$COUNTER] = 1 ]]
        then
            echo " ["$COUNTER"] "$'\x1d'" ${whatitdoes[$COUNTER]} "$'\x1d'" $(tput bold)$(tput setaf 2)Completed$(tput sgr0)"
        else
            echo "error"
        fi

        let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 

    done | column -t -s$'\x1d'

    echo "quit: Exits the program"
    echo "Choose one option:"
    read answer
done
```

Comment: `loop` has no value the first time you try to execute `[ $loop = 1 ]`. That produces an error, though not the one you claim to see.

Comment: Run your code through shellcheck.net; you have several other errors.

Comment: I saw a forgot to add the loop=1 variable so its added know but I still cant figure out whats not working

Comment: Run `/bin/bash -x myscript.sh` and provide the exact details of the error, including the line number and the statement.

Comment: *"My problem is ... parse error: `condition expected: =`"* is not very helpful. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: I just copied the content of your script to a local file and ran it. I do not receive the error you reported.

Comment: Compare your array expansion of `scriptstatus` with `whatitdoes`.

Comment: @chepner Ooooooh Thank You!!! I didnt notice xD It works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just wrote the array expansion wrongly; instead of:

```
 if [[ $scriptstatus[$COUNTER] = 0 ]]
```

I had to use:

```
 if [[ ${scriptstatus[$COUNTER]} = 0 ]]
```

The `{` and `}` are required for array subscripting.